# Where does the energy go when two waves destructively interfere?

Tags: waves, interference

Suppose two wave pulses are traveling in opposite directions, but when they superimpose, they completely cancel each other out (destructive interference)

But as soon as they pass each other, they just continue their motion with their original respective amplitude.

Now I'm wondering what happens to the energy of the waves when they are superimposed? Is the energy in the form of potential energy of the particles? It's not kinetic energy because the particles have zero displacement at that moment